# Convert from a String to a polynomial

Tags: java, polynomial-math

I am writing a program in Java that is going to be using polynomials. I need to be able to express polynomials based on something the user enters in.

For example the user might enter the following string.
"`2, -7, 8, 0, -1`"

The polynomials for this here would be `2 - 7 x + 8 x^2 - x^4`

But here's the catch. I cannot split the each number in the string into seperate ints using parse, this would be too easy! Because the String could have any number of numbers in it, this example has 5 numbers another might have 6, or less than that.

Any ideas as to how I could express a polynomial within Java?

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] split = values.split(",\\s*");
```

This regex will also take care of additional spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You should use **String.split()** and run it through a loop of Integer.valueOf() calls.

Answer (score 1):

> Any ideas as to how I could express a polynomial within java?

In my view the easiest is to have an array of `int` (or `float`/`double`) coefficients. The number of elements in the array would depend in the degree of the polynomial.

I'd wrap this in a class and use `String.split()` with `Integer.valueOf()` (or `Double.valueOf()`/`Float.valueOf()`) to construct it from `String`.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use `String.split()` and `Integer.parseInt()` then:

- make a `Polynomial` class which takes a `String` argument in its constructor

and (

- a `getNumber` method which uses `indexOf` and `substring` to return a String part
- a `getCount` method which counts the commas in the string

or

- implement [java.lang.Iterable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) interface, and use the techniques described above in the `Iterator` implementation

)

Answer (score 1):

You **can** split the string using `String.split()` without knowing the number of components. It will allocate the appropriate number of components for you.

Then convert it into an array of type `int[]` which represents your polynomial...

Nothing particularly difficult here, everything is straightforward.